# Skip first line of csv file as it has empty row in file format

Tags: c#, csvhelper

below is my generic method that returns me a object list taking Stream uploaded from csv file but i want to skip the first row as there is header from only second row of csv .  please help me to modify this code to take from second row

```
public static List<T> getList<T>(Stream str, T obj)
{            
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(str))
    {
        using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            csvReader.Read();
            csvReader.Configuration.TrimHeaders = true;
            csvReader.Configuration.TrimFields = true;
            csvReader.Configuration.IsHeaderCaseSensitive = false;
            csvReader.Configuration.IgnoreHeaderWhiteSpace = true;
            csvReader.Configuration.SkipEmptyRecords = true;
            return csvReader.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you put `reader.ReadLine()` after: `using (var reader = new StreamReader(str))`, this should skip first line

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using [`CsvHelper`](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). If that's the case the `GetRecords` method alone should be enough to map your results without headers, provided that the properties on T matches the header names in the data.

TL;DR; Remove the call to the `csvReader.Read` method and only use the `GetRecords` method.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(str))
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    csvReader.Configuration.TrimHeaders = true;
    csvReader.Configuration.TrimFields = true;
    csvReader.Configuration.IsHeaderCaseSensitive = false;
    csvReader.Configuration.IgnoreHeaderWhiteSpace = true;
    csvReader.Configuration.SkipEmptyRecords = true;
    return csvReader.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Skip method and specify the number of items you want to skip.
Like lst.Skip(1);